# Angular could not find service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I got again a small problem, I could not solve by myself.

I got some services in some files. All files are merged into one huge file by my buildsystem. The result is this (shortened):

```
/// file: _.service.js
angular.module('services', []);

/// file: aufgang.service.js
angular.module('services').factory('aufgangService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    "use strict";

    return $resource(
        configuration.api2_base_url + '/api/Aufgang/:id',
        { id: '@id' },
        {
            single: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
            get: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
        }
    );
}]);

/// file: beleg-monitor.service.js
angular.module('services').factory('belegMonitorService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    "use strict";

    return $resource(configuration.api2_base_url + '/api/BelegMonitors', {}, { get: { method: 'GET', isArray: true } });
}]);
```

this is the header of my main module

```
angular.module('mainModule', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngSanitize','services'])
```

Now i got the problem, that the injector is not able to find the service. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

1) Add angular-resource.js:  "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-resource.js"

2) Change to angular.module('mainModule', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngSanitize','services', 'ngResource'])

Comment: you are the best. I just missed the dependency ngResource for the service module.

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible reasons for this :

1. your build "forget" to add one of the files
2. If you have more than one module, check that the module where the missing dependency is detected have a dependency towards this one
3. A typo in the service's name ?

Open your console debogguer and paste the message if you want us to tell you were the missing dependency is if you have some trouble reading it.

Comment: This is the error message:  "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- clientService http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20clientService"

Comment: Solution number 2 : you forget a dependency : `angular.module('services', ['ngResource'])`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 'services' module is not available when angular.module('mainModule', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngSanitize','services']) line is executed. And the reason may be 'services' module is created in a separate file so there might be the chances that 'services' is getting created after execution of angular.module('mainModule'... line.

Try to create 'services' module in the same files in which angular.module('mainModule'... line is getting executed if not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with 'services' module because following module hirarchy is working fine. So, must missed some other dependency.

```
/// file: _.service.js
        angular.module('services', []);

        /// file: aufgang.service.js
        angular.module('services').factory('aufgangService', function ($resource) {
            "use strict";

            return function () {

            };
        });

        /// file: beleg-monitor.service.js
        angular.module('services').factory('belegMonitorService', function ($resource) {
            "use strict";

            return function () {

            };
        });

        angular.module('mainModule', ['services']);
        angular.module('mainModule').controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.Message = "Hello World !!!";
        })
```